# Create a file based on inputs provided in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to execute a curl command using jenkins, but I need to provide a json file while executing that curl.
I want to build up that file dynamically using the values passed in parameters while executing the build.

Example json file:

{
"field1": "value1"
"field2": "value2"
}

These values will be dynamic i.e it will be passed as parameters when doing the build.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Please add sample code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    parameters {
        string(name: 'NAME', defaultValue: 'Mr X', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
        string(name: 'LOCATION', defaultValue: 'NYC', description: 'Where should I report this to?')
    }
    stages {
        stage('curl') {
            steps {
                writeJSON file: 'data.json', json: params
    
                sh """
                    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json http://api.xyz.net
                    
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note - for DSL `writeJSON` need [pipeline-utility-steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) plugins to be installed or By using native groovy api you can parse `params` object to JSON.